# How to append file after string? php

Tags: php

Ok lets say I have a File called File.txt and it contains

```
Hello
World
!!!!!
```

Ok now I have it so they may Post something to add to the string But it has ot be right under the string "Hello". How would I go about doing that ?

Comment: Like, always insert at line 2? Or always after the "hello"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$mystring="string to append";
$file="file";
$data = file($file);
foreach ($data as $k=>$v){
    if ( strpos($v,"Hello") !==FALSE){
        $data[$k]=$data[$k] . "$mystring\n";
    }
}
file_put_contents($file,$data);
```

Comment: I agree This is very good Thank you Very much! +1 Great example